# How to have a luks-protected LVM volume mounted at boot

Tags: mount, lvm, luks, automounting

I have my primary Ubuntu install on one disk, and a secondary install (for offline backups of the primary) on another disk. For convenience, I would like the root volume of the second install mounted within the primary install.

I have a crypttab entry: `sda3_ubuntu UUID=XXX keyfile luks,nofail`,
and an fstab entry: `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /home/XXX/sda3_ubuntu ext4 nofail,errors=remount-ro 0 1`

Using `cryptdisks_start` and at boot, the volume is unlocked as expected. However, the root volume is never mounted because the LVM volume is inactive after it's unlocked (and thus there are no dm devices for it). If I activate it, `mount -a` successfully mounts it.

This is all very scriptable, but I feel as though I'm missing something that would automagically activate the LVM volume in between, as would happen for a boot volume. Does such a thing exist and my Google-foo is failing me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVM should be able to autoactivate the underlying VG (and LVs) after decrypting the LUKS device. The important things to check would be the LVM configuration file(s) and if the proper services are enabled and running.

/etc/lvm/lvm.conf

```
event_activation = 1
```

`auto_activation_volume_list` should not be set (the default is to activate all of the LVs).
Enabling lvmpolld (`use_lvmpolld = 1`) could also be worth a try.

The services that should be running are:

```
lvm2-monitor
dm-event
```

You can check your systemd execution chain with a command:

```
systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg
```

Look at what services start when. Maybe some service is not active or is not starting at the right time.

Comment: Thanks kurcze! I'm marking this as the accepted answer since it seems based on what I'm reading that this is correct. I'll have to read more into the systemd interactions to see what impact changing it has on my current setup.